# Multiple Linear Regression with Mediator in SPSS

Tags: multiple-regression, spss, mediation

My variables (all continuous):

- IVs: Secondary Traumatic Stress and Vicarious Traumatization
- DV: PTSD
- Mediator: Social Support

I checked the correlations between the variables and they are all significant at the 0.01 level (2-tailed).

I had a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoKVnkd3HlM) (duration 3'49"), but I fail to understand how the author finds out the mediation (I was expecting a special field for the mediator, a little bit like the covariate in an ANCOVA). The statistical result fails, in my mind, to show the mediation.

[This document](https://www.uni-trier.de/fileadmin/urt/doku/medmodreg/medmodreg.pdf) in German, on page 14, however, shows that in SPSS if we do:

1. Analyze
2. Generali Linear Model
3. Univariate…
4. Dependent Variable: PTSD
5. Fixed Factor(s): STSS, VTS
6. Covariate(s): Social Support

Results show statistically significant (p < .05) sources as follows:

- Corrected Model
- Intercept
- STSS

Marginally significant (p = [.05; .10]):

- Social Support

Non significant (p > .10):

- VTS
- STSS * VTS

Adjusted R Squared = .416

But I cannot see the correlations.

Anyone has any suggestions on how to do a Multiple Linear Regression with meditation in SPSS (or R/RStudio if need be)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact what seems to be needed in this case is a latent variable analysis or lavaan. In R/RStudio it would be as follows (all the sources are in the code). The database is an SPSS `.sav` file:

```
#lavaan: latent variable analysis (i.e., multiple linear regression with mediation)
#(Source: http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/mediation.html)

#Verify that necessary packages are installed: install them if not
#(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090169/elegant-way-to-check-for-missing-packages-and-install-them)
list.of.packages <- c("lavaan", "sem")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)

#Load libraries
#(Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/lavaan/EOuhhbZXTTw/h8DcscHrBgAJ)
library(sem)
library(lavaan)

#Set directory
setwd("~/directory_of_database/")

#Import from SPSS
#(Source: https://datascienceplus.com/get-your-data-into-r/)
library(foreign)
hypo2 <- read.spss("SPSS_File_Name.sav", use.value.label=TRUE, to.data.frame=TRUE)

#lavaan code
#(Source: http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/mediation.html)
set.seed(1234)
STSS <- hypo2$STSS_Mean #STSS = predictor
SocialSupport <- hypo2$JCQ_SocialSupport_Scale #SocialSupport = Mediator
PTSD <- hypo2$PCL5_Mean #PTSD = Dependent Variable
Data <- data.frame(STSS = STSS, PTSD = PTSD, SocialSupport = SocialSupport)
model <- ' # direct effect
             PTSD ~ c*STSS
           # mediator
             SocialSupport ~ a*STSS
             PTSD ~ b*SocialSupport
           # indirect effect (a*b)
             ab := a*b
           # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)
         '
fit <- sem(model, data = Data)
summary(fit)
```